# Alternate highest counting in array

Tags: c++, arrays

I have an array which is sorted but contains zeroes in between like

```
a[10]={0,0,3,5,0,6,7,0,9,0}
```

I want to neglect zeroes and find sum of alternate elsments i.e.
3+6+9 and 5+7 seperately. 
Here is what m trying to do

```
while(i<10)
{
     if(a[i]!=0)
     {
         s1=s1+a[i];
         i++;
     }
     if(a[i]!=0)
     {
         s2=s2+a[i]
         i++;
     }
     i++;
}
```

any alternate to this??

Comment: What are "alternate elements"?

Comment: What if you encounter 2 zeros in a row? Switch twice or just once?

Comment: we have to ignore all zeroes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a boolean to keep track of which sum to add the element to:

```
bool alt = true;
int sum1 = 0;
int sum2 = 0;
for(int i = 0; i<10; ++i)
{
    if(a[i])
    {
        if(alt)
        {
            sum1 += a[i];
        }
        else
        {
            sum2 += a[i];
        }
        alt = !alt;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can modify the array,
following does what you say (ignore zero, and then compute alternate sum):

```
int a[] = {0,0,3,5,0,6,7,0,9,0};
const auto end = std::stable_partition (std::begin(a), std::end(a),
                                        [](int e) {return e != 0;});

int sum1 = 0;
for (int i = 0; a + i < end; i += 2) { sum1 += a[i]; }
int sum2 = 0;
for (int i = 1; a + i < end; i += 2) { sum2 += a[i]; }

std::cout << sum1 << std::endl;
std::cout << sum2 << std::endl;
```

Note: if you can't use lambda (C++11),
you have to write the predicate `NotZero`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a very simple solution if I have understood correctly what you need.

```
int sum[2] = {};

int j = 0;

for ( int x : a )
{
   if ( x ) sum[j++ % 2] += x;
}
```

And here is a demontsrative program

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int a[] = { 0, 0, 3, 5, 0, 6, 7, 0, 9, 0 };

    int sum[2] = {};

    int j = 0;

    for ( int x : a )
    {
        if ( x ) sum[j++ % 2] += x;
    } 

    for ( int s : sum ) std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
```

The output

```
18
12
```

If you are using MS VC++ 2010 then you can substitute the loops in the program for the following

```
for each ( int x in a )
for each ( int s in sum ) std::cout << s << std::endl;
```

Or instead of the range based for loops you can use ordinary loops.